# Jquery Add a delay in P text swap

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").on("click", function() {
        var el = $(this);
        if (el.text() == el.data("text-swap")) {
            el.text(el.data("text-original"));
        } else {
            el.data("text-original", el.text());
            el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
        }
    });
});
```

Is it possible to add an delay in this jQuery code?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

> Sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once after the timer expires.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").on("click", function() {
        var el = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (el.text() == el.data("text-swap")) {
                el.text(el.data("text-original"));
            } else {
                el.data("text-original", el.text());
                el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain exactly what you did? 
I'm relatively new to jquery.

Comment: @simonschaminee, Follow the link, I have used `setTimeout()` which executes the statement after certain interval of milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var TIMEOUT = 1000 // 1 second
$("p").on("click", function() {
    var el = $(this);
    setTimeout( function() {
        if (el.text() == el.data("text-swap")) {
            el.text(el.data("text-original"));
        } else {
            el.data("text-original", el.text());
            el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
        }
    }, TIMEOUT);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("p").on("click", function() {
            var el = $(this);
            setTimeout(loadfn,1000);
        });
    });
    function loadfn() {
        if (el.text() == el.data("text-swap")) {
            el.text(el.data("text-original"));
        } else {
            el.data("text-original", el.text());
            el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
        }
    }
```